# Multiple LEFT Join works correct in mysql but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried mutiple LEFT JOIN in mysql it works fine there but however if use the same query in php mysqli object method I am not getting what I get in direct mysql

HERE is the Query in **MYSQL**

```
 SELECT f.*,o.*,fs.* FROM fruits f
 LEFT JOIN orders o ON f.id = o.fruit_id
 LEFT JOIN fruit_stock fs ON f.id = fs.f_id
```

**MYSQL RESULT**

```
id  name          price     id  fruit_id    qty     id  f_id    stock_qty   
3   Banana        5         2   3           10      1   3       122
3   Banana        5         4   3           8       1   3       122
2   Apple         3         1   2           3       2   2       322
4   pomegranate   4         3   4           15      3   4       23
5   grape         3         NULLNULL        NULL    4   5       12
1   mango         45        NULLNULL        NULL    NULLNULL    NULL
```

Same query with php

```
$con1 = new mysqli('***','***','***','***');
$sel_sql = 'SELECT f.*,o.*,fs.* FROM fruits f LEFT JOIN orders o ON f.id = o.fruit_id LEFT JOIN fruit_stock fs ON f.id = fs.f_id';
$result = $con1->query($sel_sql);
var_dump($result);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

I just `var_dump` the `$row` to see the result. When I see I am not getting `id` for the 6th row as seen on mysql instead I get `null`

```
array (size=7)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Banana' (length=6)
  'price' => string '5' (length=1)
  'fruit_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '10' (length=2)
  'f_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'stock_qty' => string '122' (length=3)

array (size=7)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Banana' (length=6)
  'price' => string '5' (length=1)
  'fruit_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '8' (length=1)
  'f_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'stock_qty' => string '122' (length=3)

array (size=7)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Apple' (length=5)
  'price' => string '3' (length=1)
  'fruit_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '3' (length=1)
  'f_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'stock_qty' => string '322' (length=3)

array (size=7)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'pomegranate' (length=11)
  'price' => string '4' (length=1)
  'fruit_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '15' (length=2)
  'f_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'stock_qty' => string '23' (length=2)

array (size=7)
  'id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'grape' (length=5)
  'price' => string '3' (length=1)
  'fruit_id' => null
  'qty' => null
  'f_id' => string '5' (length=1)
  'stock_qty' => string '12' (length=2)

array (size=7)
  'id' => null
  'name' => string 'mango' (length=4)
  'price' => string '45' (length=2)
  'fruit_id' => null
  'qty' => null
  'f_id' => null
  'stock_qty' => null
```

I am expecting to get the **id** from the fruit table(which is 1 and the fruit name is mango) but its returning `null`.

Not sure why is that happening. Any help?
`fruit_stock` TABLE

```
 id     f_id    stock_qty
 1      3       122
 2      2       322
 3      4       23
 4      5       12
```

`orders` Table

```
 id     fruit_id    qty
 1      2           3
 2      3           10
 3      4           15
 4      3           8
```

I don't want to care about id in other table I just want the main(fruits) table id and other corresponding whole data from other tables.

Comment: you have multiple id fields, which are overwriting each other. if you want them all you will have to alias them

Comment: There is 3 `id` columns, what are they? It seems the `id` in your final array is the third one. Use alis to keep the good id

Comment: @olibiaz I put other table in my question for information

Comment: @rram have a look at my answer please

Comment: @nogad I already aliased the table with f, o, fs do they need additional work in alias. Can't I use * to get all datas from other table

Comment: You have several column with the same name `id` so you have to alias them or remove them. php don't keep the alias of the tables. If you need all the ids, alias the column name.

Comment: Or use `fetch_row()` instead of `fetch_assoc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add alias to your ids or remove the useless ones (optional ones are commented):

```
$sel_sql = 'SELECT 
    f.*,
    -- o.id as order_id, 
    o.fruit_id,
    o.qty,
    -- fs.id as fruit_stock_id,
    fs.f_id,
    fs.stock_id
 FROM fruits f LEFT JOIN orders o ON f.id = o.fruit_id LEFT JOIN fruit_stock fs ON f.id = fs.f_id';
```

Then you will have only one index `id` on your array.

Comment: thank you I guess since the result is an associative array the value are overwritten am I correct?

Comment: Thank you for the additional info on aliasing each id field to avoid the override. Thumbs Up

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one key with a value of `Id` so when the query runs it is first 1 and then when it hits the 2nd `Id` it overwrites it with `null` note that you only have 1 Id in your array but two in the query. You will need to be a bit more selective in the query and alias some of the columns.